# Fix JQuery-1.4.1 and json-2.0 conflict in json.parse regex conflict with "$" character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

After upgrading to jquery 1.4.1 i noticed there was an error anytime i tried calling json.parse. The issue is part of the regex used in json. it uses a $ in the pattern that conflicts with JQuery's $ shortcut.

I don't want to use the non-conflict option with jquery because i have tons of places i'd have to replace the $ with the new corrected shortcut.

Is there a way to wrap a regex pattern in single quotes or something so the pattern string is handled as literally a string?

Broken section in json-2.0.js: (fails on the $)

```
if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.
test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {
.....
}
```

Thanks

## Update:

The problem was not as it appeared and didn't have to do with a `$` conflict. From the OP:

> The error was bombing on `test.replace` because the object that was passed in was already deserialized so the method `replace` was not found. I guess upgrading to JQuery 1.4.1 had some changes in the way the result object is handled on the success event of the `$.ajax` function.

Comment: How sure are you that this is happening?  It seems pretty inlikely, because that dollar is syntactically distinct from the "$" used as an identifier for the jQuery function. Just like if you have a variable called "foo" the regex /foo/ won't be confused. When you say it "fails", what exactly happens?

Comment: When i roll back my reference to jquery jquery-1.3.2.js i don't have this problem. i've checked in firebug, and VS2008.net's js debugger. both think that the $ in the pattern is the JQuery object.

Comment: Well I've run my large, jQuery-laden site with the new library, and I've got regex expressions with dollar signs all over the place, and I have no problems at all. What exactly did Firebug tell you, or do, that makes you think that it thinks the $ regex special character is actually the jQuery object?

Comment: When you say "json.parse", do you mean "$.parseJSON()" or are you using some other JSON library?

Comment: @Pointy: I think he/she is using json-2.0.js.

Comment: LOL ignore everything i have to say :) The error was bombing on "test.replace" the object that was passed in was already deserialized so the method "replace" was not found. I guess upgrading to JQuery 1.4.1 had some changes in the way the result object is handled on the success event of the $.ajax function. i just needed an extra cup of coffee.

Sorry! Can i delete this question?

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Yeah, you should be able to (delete the question).

Comment: Aww there are too many answers to delete the question. Now i'm stuck looking like an idiot on the internets forever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a page that pulls in jQuery 1.4.1 and json2.js, and it calls JSON.parse(), and it gets no exceptions or errors: http://gutfullofbeer.net/json.html

Answer (score 3):

Are you **sure** it's failing on the `$`, and for that reason? Because that's a massive namespacing/parsing failure if so. There's no reason at all the JavaScript engine should be looking for an external symbol there. It's *already* encapsulated in the way you asked about (by the slashes, which are effectively quotes for a regex). If that were really the problem, it would be every bit as surprising as the interpreter choking on a $ inside a string. I think your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The error was bombing on `test.replace` the object that was passed in was already deserialized so the method `replace` was not found. I guess upgrading to JQuery 1.4.1 had some changes in the way the result object is handled on the success event of the `$.ajax` function.

**This question should be deleted**

Apparently this question cannot be deleted with the amount of answers that have been suggested.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying this to the question itself. (You can edit questions.)